# ReferenceError: computed is not defined on Vitest test suite

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vitest

### Description

I'm migrating test suites from Jest to Vitest.
But i've a problem when i run test suites, an error occurs when a component has a computed property.

The common error is :

```
ReferenceError: computed is not defined

 - /components/Ui/Avatar.vue:13:30
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:157:22
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7084:29
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7039:11
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5401:13
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5376:17
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:4978:21
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5515:21
 - /node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:189:25
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5622:56
```

#### Versions

- "vitest": "^0.18.1"
- "jsdom": "^20.0.0"
- "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.2"

### Exemple

Here is my component code :

```js
<template>
  <image
    :src="src"
    :onerror="onErrorLoadImage"
    :class="['avatar', { big }]"
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
  src?: string
  big?: boolean
  errorImage?: string
}>(), {
  src: '',
  big: false,
  errorImage: '/no-avatar.png',
})

const onErrorLoadImage = computed(() => `this.src='${props.errorImage}';this.onerror='';`)
</script>
```

And my test

```js
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import UiAvatar from './Avatar.vue'

const componentName = 'img'
const src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNk+A8AAQUBAScY42YAAAAASUVORK5CYII='
const big = true
const errorImage = '/no-avatar.png'

describe('UiAvatar', () => {
  it('should be render the component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(UiAvatar, {
      propsData: {
        src,
        big,
        errorImage
      }
    })
    expect(wrapper.element.tagName).toBe(componentName)
  })
})
```

Thanks :)

Comment: same issue, have you solved it yet?

Comment: @weiL. not solved, but my temporary fix is to import required modules on the component. Like for exemple when i have the error "computed is not defined" when i run test suites, i've added the module in the component file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by using the following npm packages:
unplugin-vue-components/vite
unplugin-auto-import/vite

They only need to specify a path where the import files will be generated, in my case I use a storybook folder since I also use the plugin there, but it can be any other path

[vitest.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQA87.png)